# Mejor lenguaje para interactuar con un javascript externo

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Estoy realizando una página web en donde debo utilizar información de una página externa, para ello necesito que la página se conecte con la externa con un usuario y su contraseña y obtener los datos que la página me muestre.

Tengo conocimientos en `Java` pero no en `Javascript` por lo que me recomendaron utilizar `PhantomJS`, ya que la página externa trabaja con un `javascript` para ingresar, pero he tenido problemas utilizando el programa y se dificulta aun mas para subirlo a una web.

¿Habrá otro lenguaje que permita ejecutar ficheros `javascript` externos y obtener infornamción?

He pensado que `AJAX` podría funcionar pero no se si tiene la capacidad de ejecutar `javascript` externos.

Comment: Para enviar datos tales como usuarios y contraseñas debes usar lengunjes del lado del servidor como php.

Comment: AJAX no es un lenguaje, es una técnica de desarrollo.

Comment: Podrías crear un fichero en el servidor (con PHP, Java, o el lenguaje que quieras) cuyo objetivo sea hacer la conexion al servidor externo (con las credenciales necesarias), leer el archivo JS y servirlo. De este modo podrías incluirlo en tu página como si fuese local

Comment: El mejor lenguaje para hacer eso es el propio javascript. Si no lo sabes es momento de que lo aprendas. Te recomiendo estos dos tutoriales de javascript http://www.desarrolloweb.com/manuales/20/ y su continuación http://www.desarrolloweb.com/manuales/20/#manual26 Con eso yo aprendí las bases javascript como en DOS SEMANAS y libre mi problema, ya tiempo después compre el gran libro de html, css y javascript; y ahora salio una especie de continuación el gran libro de html5, css3 y javascript. Ademas de que todo esto son las bases para que aprendas AJAX (jquery o DWR o etc).

Answer (score 0):

Desde tu propio script (en javascript, en el navegador especialmente) puedes cargar e invocar otros scripts, siempre y cuando no te limiten los permisos de acceso (CORS).

Dos ejemplos: [jQuery.getScript](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) que además si la carga del script fue exitosa, te permite ejecutar una función propia como callback.

Otro ejemplo son los códigos para cargar google analytics o los SDK de facebook y twitter en una página. Tomemos uno como ejemplo:

```
// esta es una función anónima que se invoca inmediatamente "IIFE"
(function(d, s, id){
     /* primero busca un elemento con la etiqueta <script> */
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     /* si encontró un elemento con el id facebook-jssdk, aborta */
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     /* en caso contrario, crea un <script> con el id ya dicho */
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     /* y le asigna la url desde lo va a cargar a: */
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     /* y lo inserta en el documento, haciendo que el navegador lo cargue */
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
// esta última línea te muestra los argumentos con que se invoca la función
```

Finalmente, te recomiendo que leas [acerca del control de acceso](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS), si estás en el mismo host puedes cargar scripts del mismo fácilmente, pero si quieres cargar desde otro host, tienes que configurar las cabeceras de permisos.